# A strange behavior in a collection filter

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, cart, collection

For the pro collections I have a question for you !

I want to filter the **cart collection items** in `checkout/cart.phtml` like this:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$items->addFieldToFilter('sku', 123);
```

`var_dump($items->getSize())` renders me `int(1)` it's my filtered product that i want, while basically I have three items in a cart. Good.

Now if I do :

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    var_dump($item->getSku());
}
```

This renders me the **three** items ???

Comment: After playing arround yesterday I already asked this :)

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't know, and I left you a message that I will ask this question, no problem, I'll delete it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer of your question. But in such issues I always use ->getSelect() ->__toString() for collection. It helps me to understand which sql query magento uses right now. So it helps to debug.